# Google App Script returning "Attribute provided with no value"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm attempting to use the `UrlFetchApp` method to check a large sheet of (around 2000) rows where some of the links are no longer needed. They don't give a 404, so I'm searching the html of the link for the class `error`. My logic appears to be functioning more or less as I want it to, with rows containing links with the class `error` being passed into an array.

The issue I'm having is that the script is failing after a few minutes with the error `Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url`. Previously I was getting `Address unavailable`, but since wrapping `UrlFetchApp` in a `try-catch` I'm not seeing that anymore.

```
//If link is dead, delete
function deleteRows() {
  
  //Check sheet for links where the car has been sold
function checkLinks(url){
  try{
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var searchstring = 'class="error"';
  var index = html.search(searchstring);
  return index > 0;
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Facebook Feed")
  var rows = ss1.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var toDelete = [];

  for (var row = 1; row < values.length; row += 1) {
    for(var column = 0; column < values[row].length; column += 1){
      if (checkLinks(values[row][7])){
              Logger.log(row);
           toDelete.push(row);
      } 
    }
  }
  Logger.log(toDelete);
  for(var deleteRow = toDelete.length-1; deleteRow >= 0; deleteRow -= 1){
    ss1.deleteRow(toDelete[deleteRow]+1);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: It means `checkLinks(values[row][7])` for some row was empty, and UrlFetchApp needs it to have a value. This was caught by your catch inside `checkLinks(url)` so do you know in which row this happened ? And what value was it for `url`?

Comment: Just checked and there was a link missing in the sheet I ran this code on - thanks for taking a look.